# XSLT can't get value of nested node

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following xml:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
    <IsAliveResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <IsAliveResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Regulatory.Compliance.Screening.DTOs.MessageContracts" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <CorrelationId xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Services.Common">4cd91989-1142-4a9c-8f40-149a47078c90</CorrelationId>
        <ErrorMessages xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Services.Common" xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Services.Common.Models"/>
        <Status xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Services.Common">Success</Status>
      </IsAliveResult>
    </IsAliveResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>`

And I need to get the value of the **Status** node through an XSLT transform. No Matter what I try, I can't go deeper than the `s:body` node.

Here is my XSLT:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Regulatory.Compliance.Screening.DTOs.MessageContracts" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Services.Common" >
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="/s:Envelope/s:Body" />
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>`

If I change the `xsl:value-of select` to `/s:Envelope/s:Body/IsAliveResponse/IsAliveResult/Status` then nothing is returned.

Could anyone explain why that transform doesn't work and how I can successfully retrieve the **Status** value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to watch the namespaces more carefully - esp. the default ones. Try:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:t="http://tempuri.org/"
xmlns:c="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Services.Common">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="/s:Envelope/s:Body/t:IsAliveResponse/t:IsAliveResult/c:Status" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```